# Are wheels from Duplo numbers' train set 10558 compatible with bridge 3774?

Tags: trains, compatibility, duplo

Are the wheels from Duplo set [10558](http://brickset.com/sets/10558-1/Number-Train) compatible with the railway bridge set [3774](http://brickset.com/sets/3774-1/Bridge)?

I have a number of older wheel bases that are too large for the bridge. According to Brickset, the wheels in set 10558 have the [same design number](http://brickset.com/parts/design-14639) as parts from 20 years back but the design is visibly different with small embossed details on the side of the wheel. Also the wheels on pictures seem a little bit narrower than my older wheels.

Can anyone confirm whether the wheels are indeed narrow enough for climbing the bridge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the wheels are too wide. You'll have a similar problem with the DUPLO points as well.

If I recall correctly, the wheel base on the trucks is too long for the DUPLO track corners as well.

You'll need one of the trains from [10507](http://brickset.com/sets/10507-1/My-First-Train-Set) or [10508](http://brickset.com/sets/10508-1/Deluxe-Train-Set) to use that bridge.

Sadly my kids have outgrown their DUPLO and it's now at the back of our loft otherwise I'd post a picture (and confirm the issue with the corners).

Comment: Thanks, you prevented me from buying the wrong Christmas present for my youngest kid!

Comment: Well, all LEGO's good, but some is clearly better than others ;) I've seen similar disappointments with other "trains" that have those chunky wheels for the trucks - depending on the way you are going, you may be able to get a second-hand set of [5606 - My First Train](http://brickset.com/sets/5606-1/My-First-Train) that had the right wheels but no tracks, but if you were thinking of getting the bridge to go with an existing set, then sadly you're probably out of luck.